# Rapidminer- TF-IDF from csv dataset

Tags: machine-learning, tf-idf, rapidminer, text-analysis

I have to calculate tf-idf of two columns of csv file..
Should i have to convert the rows into text files? or is there any method to calculate tf-idf from csv.

how can i calculate tfidf of columns of csv file.

Answer (score 0):

There is an operator called `Generate TFIDF` that might be able to do what you want. The Help for the operator offers up a sample process where it is used and this might be enough for your specific needs.